# Why is my website working in my local host but not my Github Deploy Link?

Tags: html, css, browser, localhost, github-actions

So I have made this website, with two pages. Both pages, and links to both pages work perfectly well in both Safari and Chrome, in my local host. But for some reason the both menu items, linking to an 'About' page and on the second page, there is a link to 'Home', don't work in my GitHub deploy link. Shared here: https://hajmub.github.io/sounds/

I get this error message (linked above) when I click onto the 'About' page, in the deploy link.

Yet it seem to still be fine in my local host, on both browsers. Does anyone know what's going on?

Can it be something wrong with the code, if it seems to be working fine in the local server?

Have tried everything! Looked at markup indentation, all css properties, checking every aspect to make sure that the menu items markup and css were exactly the same across both pages - as... if the properties and markup are the same as yesterday's (when they were working) what's changed? Why don't they work now?

Answer (score 1):

Your link is wrong in this element.

```
<a href="/second_page.html">About</a>
```

The leading `/` indicates a path starting from the web root, but your site is not in the web root, so the link fails. (On your own server the site **is** in the web root, so it works)

Change the link to this:

```
<a href="second_page.html">About</a>
```

Note: no `/`. This links to a page relative to the current page. It should work on both servers.

Comment: Verified with Inspect and Developer Tools on Chrome. Fixing paths `href` makes this work i.e. removing `/` or changing `/` to `./`. Good catch!

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for responding! I've tried this now, and the link on the first page does link to the second page, but unfortunately the menu link from the second page linking back to the first page, "Home" now doesn't work. 

I have tried it both like this "second_page.html" and like this "/second_page.html"

this is the link: https://hajmub.github.io/sounds/

Comment: You have the same problem in the link to your home page as you had in the link to your second page. Apply the same solution.

Comment: hmm - I mean I've tried both solutions. I've tried taking away the '/', ie. what I have been told to do for the first, and also keeping it in. It hasn't worked either way?